# mysql - join data between two tables when "where" clause comes from a third table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a list of questions in one database table, imagery in another, and image categories in another.

In the image categories table, I have a column with the question id pertaining to the category.

In the imagery table, I have a column with the category id that corresponds to the image category.

I want to select all the questions, and grab the images belonging to that question, but to do this, I need to say something like:

```
select (*) from questions
join (imagery)
where (image_category.question_id = questions.id AND image_category.id = image.category_id)
```

How would I write this in SQL. I apologize - I don't have a strong hold on the syntax yet for explaining the question. I've done joins, but not just with multiple contingencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT q.*, ic.*, i.*
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN image_category ic
ON ic.question_id = q.id
INNER JOIN imagery i
ON ic.id = i.cetegory_id
```